# Changing notification buttton icon on click

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I made a custom layout for my notification, it has two buttons one for play and one for pausing the music. When i click on each button a broadcast is sent to the respective class.

[image: notification]

Now i want to keep only one button and (toggle)change the icon of the button when the user taps the button from play to pause and vice versa, I tried several things to **change the icon**(my real problem) but failed so far.

In PlayerActivity.java I displays the notification by calling this line.

```
NotificationGenerator.customBigNotification(getApplicationContext());
```

Here is the code of NotifcationGenerator :

```
package com.example.user.musicplayer;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class NotificationGenerator {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_OPEN_ACTIVITY = 1;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_CUSTOM_BIG = 1;

    public static void customBigNotification(Context context){
        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.big_notification);
        NotificationCompat.Builder nc = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, PlayerActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        notifyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        String id = "mymusicplayer";
        CharSequence name = "player";
        String description = "player";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;

        NotificationChannel mChannel = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(description);

            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);

            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});

            nm.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }



        nc.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        nc.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
        nc.setAutoCancel(true);
        nc.setCustomBigContentView(expandedView);
        nc.setContentTitle("Music Player");
        nc.setContentText("Control Audio");
        nc.getBigContentView().setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, "Lorem Ipsum Dolor");

        setRemoteViews(expandedView, context);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID_CUSTOM_BIG, nc.setChannelId(id).build());
    }

    private static void setRemoteViews(RemoteViews remoteViews, Context c) {

        // call broadcast when any control of notification is clicked.
        Intent playIntent = new Intent(c, PlayBroadcast.class);

        PendingIntent playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, playIntent, 0);

        // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlay, playPendingIntent);

        // call broadcast when any control of notification is clicked.
        Intent pauseIntent = new Intent(c, PauseBroadcast.class);

        PendingIntent pausePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, pauseIntent, 0);

        // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPause, pausePendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Here is the code of PlayBroadCast.java : (where the broadcast from the play button is received) :

```
package com.example.user.musicplayer;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class PlayBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        MediaPlayer mP = PlayerActivity.mediaPlayer;
        if(!mP.isPlaying()){
            mP.start();

        }
    }
}
```

Pardon me if the explanation is not clear, because if i might have the correct words to explain it. I would have googled it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your buttons clickListeners() make a new notification with same id and view changes then notify it. Your notification will be updated with new views.

Comment: Any idea how we can handle this scenario in a React Native App?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expandedLayout.setInt(R.id.notif_button_play, "setImageResource", R.drawable.ic_play)
```

In my case the view was ImageButton, so I changed the icon through "setImageResource". You can set the function name of your view.